# What to do when journal comments to rewrite the article?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, editors

What to do when a journal editor comments to rewrite (revise and resubmit) the article to remove similarities from another paper published in the same journal by our group. The works are different but the writing style may be same. In this case, is it recommended to submit in the same journal after rewriting or should I go for another journal?

Comment: Can you clarify how the journal editor decided about your article? Did they say (a) it's accepted but edit it to be less similar (b) it's accepted if you're willing to make the revisions, (c) revise and resubmit, or (d) we don't accept it *but* if you rewrite it we might accept it. / Without this I don't know how anyone can give a competent answer.

Comment: @virmaior it is in revise and resubmit phase.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain relevant information from your comments.

Comment: Relevant details added.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, the editor felt that your manuscript has too much overlap with another publication of you(r group). This may simply be indicated to them by a computer program which checks for literal overlaps with any source.

Often papers from the same authors suffer from such overlaps, in particular in the introduction section. However, this **self plagiarism** should be avoided, even if only by rephrasing the text. Duplication of content (even if rephrased) elsewhere (than in the introduction) is less acceptable and should be limited to the necessary minimum.

In any case you should add an appropriate reference to your previous work, for example "*see also paper 1, where we have explained all this in more detail*".

Comment: As a reader and user of academic papers, I find this custom really frustrating. I have wasted a lot of my time comparing two papers trying decide if a difference in wording is significant, or just to avoid using the same wording to mean the same thing in two papers.